# How to search all tables in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

**EDIT:  Updated to include some current code for context, and added questions in bold**

Newbie here:

I will have 20 or so tables of manufacturers filled with 15,000-100,000 rows of parts in each table. Information such as PartNumber, Superceding Part Number, List Price, MFG Price, Sale Price, etc will be stored as columns.  I would like to be able to start typing a part number in a search box and have it display all the parts that match the numbers so far, and then update as I enter more of the number.

I currently have a version working with 1 table of 40,000 parts where as I type a few numbers such as '0000', it will return the top 5 parts beginning with 0000, such as: 000011, 000013,00015,000023, and 000025 and some corresponding info on them. If I type one more number '00002' it will only display 000023 and 000025.  However I would like this search to run over all tables in the database in case I do not know which manufacturer made the part.

**Currently I have a database named taft_test1, with two tables named ariens_prices and briggs_prices.  Each table will contain the same columns, but possibly not have  them filled with data on every entry.**

Any ideas on the best way to go about this?

**Some have mentioned UNION which is ok but should I do 20+ unions or might there be a better way to layout the database?**

Appreciate the help.

**Sample Code I have working:**

partslookup.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>Taft Power Equipment</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.horizontalNav.js"></script>

    <script>
    // When document is ready...
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.full-width').horizontalNav({}); // Call horizontalNav on the navigations wrapping element
        });
    </script>


    <script>
        function showUser(str)
        {
            if (str=="")
              {
              document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
              return;
              } 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                      }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                      {
                      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                      }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="inside">

            <div id="header">
                <a href="file:///C:/Users/ryan/Desktop/websites/ryan%20website/index.html"><img src="images/TaftLogo2.png" alt="header" /></a>
            </div>

            <div id="menu">
                <nav class="horizontal-nav full-width horizontalNav-notprocessed">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="partslookup.php">Parts Look Up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div id="main-content">     

                <input id="test" class="auto" type="text" size="25" placeholder="Enter Part Here" onkeyup="showUser(this.value)"        
                <br><br><br>
                <div id="txtHint"><b>Part info will display here.</b></div>         
                <br><br><br><br>    

            </div>

            <div style="clear: both;"></div>

            <div id="footer">
                <p>&copy Copy Right Taft Power Equipment Corp</p>
            </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

livesearch.php

```
<?php

$q = $_GET['q'];

echo "Part Entered:       $q   <br><br>";


$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `briggs_prices` WHERE briggs_prices.Description LIKE '$q%' 
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM `ariens_prices` WHERE ariens_prices.Description LIKE '$q%'
        LIMIT 0, 50 ";

mysql_select_db('taft_test1');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Part#</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['SuperNum'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LIST1'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
} 
echo "</table>";




while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Part# :{$row['Description']}   ".
         "Desc : {$row['SuperNum']}  ".
         "Cost : {$row['LIST1']}  ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
//echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Add all your manufacturers in one table.

Comment: you can use `union` in query

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you have 20 identical tables that are only differentiated by the brand of manufacturer? What if you'll need add a new one? You'll create more tables? Sounds really flawed to me... Maybe I'd start with proper understanding of database design....

Comment: seems a bad schema if manufacturers is not in one table.

Comment: the issue with having all manufacturers in one table is that for each manufacturer there are 20,000-100,000 parts * 20 manufacturers = 40,000 - 2,000,000 parts in a single table.  Wouldn't that make the search sluggish if it was toward the higher end?  So it seems I may need to look into database schema. Perhaps have a manufacturer table where I give them each a unique key, and then a parts table containing all parts and also that unique key.  Just trying to get something of an idea before asking another question.  Thank you

Comment: This is a really late comment, but NO JavaNinja, if you use proper indexes it will be just as fast as keeping them in seperate tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a better database layout.  Something like:

```
(P) means Primary Key
(F) means Foreign Key
(I) means Indexed

manufacturers
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    name                varchar(50)
    ...

+----+--------+-----+
| id | name   | ... |
+----+--------+-----+
|  1 | Ariens | ... |
|  2 | Briggs | ... |
| .. | ...... | ... |
+----+--------+-----+

parts
    id                      unsigned int(P)
    number                  char(50)(I)
    manufacturer_id         unsigned int(F manufacturers.id)
    name                    varchar(75)
    superceding_part_id     unsigned int(F parts.id) // Allow NULL
    list_price              double
    manufacturer_price      double
    sale_price              double
    ...

+----+--------+-----------------+----------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+------------+-----+
| id | number | manufacturer_id | name     | superceding_part_id | list_price | manufacturer_price | sale_price | ... |
+----+--------+-----------------+----------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+------------+-----+
|  1 | 000011 |               1 | Widget A | NULL                |       1.00 |                .50 |        .90 | ... |
|  2 | 000012 |               1 | Widget B |                   1 |       2.00 |                .75 |       1.75 | ... |
|  3 | 000013 |               2 | Widget A | NULL                |       1.15 |                .70 |       1.00 | ... |
| .. | ...... | ............... | ........ | ................... | .......... | .................. | .......... | ... |
+----+--------+-----------------+----------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  I will research into database schema and begin with something like this on my journey.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

examples `$part` is the variable you're typing. Here is the query

```
$query = 'SELECT TOP 5 PartNumber FROM yourTable WHERE PartNumber LIKE "'.$part.'%"'
```

Comment: OP got this part running he wants to get the result from multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you have same column in all the tables, better try UNION to get rows from single query. Have a Try

```
WHERE `PartNumber` LIKE "0001%"
```